# Wix check if .net 2.0 is installed without condition the setup

Tags: .net, wix

i have a wix project.
I want insert in it a check for .net 2.0 that if there isn't in the machine generates a warning and not an error. In that mode the user can continue with the installation and install after the .net.

I saw this:

```
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 2.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
<![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK20]]>
```

But with this code the installation of wix project doesn't continue if the .net isn't found.

How can I do?

Comment: If you put the <Condition> into root element, it's failing will terminate the whole installation. However, I'm not sure how to display warning only, as I have only basic knowledge of WiX.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom dialog or a custom action to just show the warning, all the easy built in support is for showing an error. This answer shows how to [create a custom dialog to display the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814103/23852). A custom action could also be created to call `::MsiProcessMessage()` and set the `INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING` flag. This answer shows how to send a [warning using ::MsiProcessMessage() using managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126130/23852).

Good luck. This would be easier is there was something built into the Windows Installer to show warning messages.