# Disable restore point creation for MSI

Tags: c#, windows, wix, installation, windows-installer

I know from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that creating the property *MSIFASTINSTALL* to 1 will disable restore point creation during that msi installation. But this property is supported only Windows Installer 5.0 onwards. However, I cannot guarantee 5.0 will always be present on the system. Is there some other way I can do the same thing on lower version of Windows Installer? I don't mind using a Custom Action if needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't disable system restore with a custom action** - it may fail to put it back on and you have a huge deployment bug that will really freak out system administrators everywhere.

I assume what you are looking for is a faster setup installation? You can find some tips on [**speeding up MSI installations**](https://serverfault.com/a/594661/20599) on serverfault.com. The **DISABLEROLLBACK** property seems to be available on MSI 4.

Comment: Agreed, in this case it's not the job of the install to do a system-wide change to restore points - that's the user's decision.

Comment: Yes, and worse yet: the whole software may be rejected by a company's IT department because of such constructs. Don't underestimate the importance of proper deployment and system administration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22737069/129130

Comment: I do not want to disable system restore system-wide; only for my own msi - which is what the property I had mentioned does.

Comment: Setting DISABLEROLLBACK would cause problems in case of installation failure - leaving me no easy way to undo changes done by the installer in case of failure. The restore point however is not used by the installer ever.

Answer (score 1):

Please see: [System Restore Points and the Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> On Windows XP, the installer may create checkpoints during the first
>   installation of an application, and during its removal. The installer
>   only creates checkpoints in these cases when the change is run with at
>   least a basic UI. Installations having the user interface level set to
>   None are usually initiated by the system or an application that should
>   handle creating a checkpoint. For more information, see System
>   Restore.

Comment: I had read this article before posting and confirmed that system restore points are not created in case the installation is run silently. Looking for a way I can do the same for my msi in case it is installed with UI.