# Deploy C# program without installer

Tags: c#, deployment, installation

Is there a way I can deploy my C# program as a .exe that does not need an installer? It's a simple program. I just want users to be able to download the .exe and run it or run the .exe directly from a USB drive.

Will users run into any problem like requiring .NET Framework or something if I'm able to do this?

Comment: Yes, they will. You need .NET Framework in order to run .NET compiled binaries.

Comment: A .NET program requires the NET Framework.

Comment: However the .NET Framework is automatically installed on most computers. Evaluate carefully if you need to target the latest framework, or if for example 4.0 is sufficient for your needs. That is by default installed down to XP SP2 if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot more to deployment than just a file copy. Here is a short summary: [What is the benefit and real purpose of program installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733889/what-is-the-benefit-and-real-purpose-of-program-installation)

Answer (score 0):

You can [embed all the dlls into the exe and load them as they are needed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) using the following code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => { 

   String resourceName = "AssemblyLoadingAndReflection." + 

      new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll"; 

   using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)) { 

      Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length]; 

      stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length); 

      return Assembly.Load(assemblyData); 

   } 

};
```