# Sqlite Data base not work after creating windows installer using Excelsior JET

Tags: sqlite, windows-installer, eclipse-rcp

**Trying to build an installer using Excelsior JET**

I am trying to create an installer for Eclipse RCP application product.
My product is working fine only concern is when i try to make windows installer (using Excelsior JET and install creator) **the database does not update.**

Comment: You could provide some steps of what you're doing or some printscreens, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I have followed the same steps as shown in the video                                  https://www.excelsiorjet.com/tutorials/eclipse-rcp

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at the tutorial (since it is flash), but *is the problem that the MSI does not overwrite an existing database file on installation*? If so, this normally has to do with MSI's default [**file versioning rules**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599(v=vs.85).aspx) - and how it will **preserve modified, unversioned files** - in essence non-versioned files that have different create and modify date stamps. This issue is a common confusion associated with MSI deployments.

---

I will check back to see if this is the problem. In the mean time, here is a link to an answer describing ways to deploy data files and per-user files and settings: [Create folder and file on Current user profile, from Admin Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189243/create-folder-and-file-on-current-user-profile-from-admin-profile/48196886#48196886). You might want to install a read-only database file to a per-machine location, and then copy it to the user profile upon application launch.