# WIX MSI Installer NeverOverwrite is at odds with upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I created an MSI and am now looking to extend it for patches and upgrades.  During the process of creating the original installer, I found that self-repair or resiliency kept kicking in.  I found the problem was that the MSI contained files that were intended to be modified by the end user (configuration files).  The only real solutions I found to this problem was to:

```
1) Not include the configuration files.
2) Mark all the components that represent the configuration files with NeverOverwrite='Yes'
```

I opted for #2.  Unfortunately this has completely messed up the upgrade process since the MSI Updater will not overwrite the configuration files.  I have tried messing with [REINSTALLMODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/reinstallmode).  I have also tried manually deleting the configuration files during the uninstall process.  Nothing I have tried lays down any file marked with NeverWrite during the upgrade process.

Assuming I keep NeverOverwrite, are there other options for forcing the installer to update NeverOverwrite files during an upgrade?
'
Assuming I get rid of NeverOverwrite, are there any other suggestions for preventing the self-repair process from kicking in when the configuration files are modified?

Thanks a lot for any insight you might have.

Comment: [I have a long answer on settings files here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189243/create-folder-and-file-on-current-user-profile-from-admin-profile/48196886#48196886). Where are the settings files located? Are they in a user writable location? (would be strange if they are not, but they could be opened for write permissions under program files).

Comment: The entire application installs outside of Program Files.  There were way too many things going on during the running of the application that were complicated by the restrictions on Program Files.  It was much easier to install everything outside of it, then it was to deal with the restrictions.

Comment: OK, please skim the linked answer. Maybe you can migrate to a more cloud-based approach or some other style of storage? Hopefully not taking you in the wrong direction.

Comment: Please feel free to add your own answer and accept it with chosen solution, if you have the time. Always interesting to see what people end up with.